# Varying <td> width while evenly padding cells on dynamic nav table

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have a table at the top of my website that consists of a table at 100% width, a single row, and then several table divisions. The number of nav divisions depends on what page you are on and is generated dynamically, so there is no way to easily set td widths. Additionally, I am trying to use a small image of an arrow as a sort of bullet point to each nav item, with each nav item's text centered, though I may end up removing this if I cannot get it to align.

My end goal is to have anywhere from 6-10 items on the nav bar, with varying sizes to fit the text, while evenly distributing those td cells within the bar, evenly spaced. My problems arise when I try to use both the arrow and the text together, since the text is automatically being wordwrapped onto the next line rather than in line with the text. This makes the table oddly shaped. Additionally, in some cases I have tried, the first cell may have the right size of padding I had set, like 7px left for example, but by the end of the table row, the spacing is completely wrong, like close to 50px.

Is there a sort of div, td, and CSS combination to make this work? Would I be better off making it out of divs instead? I am running out of ideas how to align these cells evenly while maintaining my nav format. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a screen capture of what I am currently at: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27295687/Untitled.png

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle, or link to the live version, so we can see the code.

Comment: I am all for divs if you are not displaying tabular data/charts/etc.  Divs are easier to work with.

Comment: I would suggest you to use CSS navigation menu instead of using a table. http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-navigation-menu.shtml

Comment: In fact, @Tim, isn't using a `<div>` or other applicable element when not displaying tabular data considered best practice?

Comment: @Matt, as far as I know, yes, div is best practice, and a situation like this, it would be best practice.... however, to each his own.  Using div + css has a longer learning curve (IMO), and making something on the fly, a table is sometimes easier, though bad practice.

Comment: @Matt: There really isn't a good way to get multiple equal-length columns with just `<div>`s and CSS yet. It can be done but it's miserable, while a *really* simple table can do it. But you have to use `role="presentation"` so screen-readers and the like know it's not supposed to be tabular data. Other than that, though, tables-for-layout are not good.

Comment: @DragoonWraith in all honesty, I didn't read the question in its entirety, I was just commenting on Tim's comment.

Comment: strictly speaking, the navigation is a list of links, thus a ul/ol with nested li's is the most correct way to go. Definitly no tables for me...

Comment: @watson, unfortunately, no I cannot, it is a locally hosted website on an embedded Linux system for an unreleased product.

And Tim, I think I am going to try this route, it seems much easier to work with, especially since I am only using a single row. But then there is still the question of even spacing that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Well, that method added some more issues and some problems with gaps and distribution, so I just decided it wasn't worth it and used | as an item separator with some padding instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajrGG/) what you are trying to do?

I guess the key CSS attribute is `table-layout: fixed;` on the table element

Answer (score 0):

You **need** to show us the code that made this bar. There are a hundred ways to make this in HTML.

This could happen if your arrow images are wrapped in a `<div>`. Div-s automatically take up an entire line by having `width: 100%`. Make sure your image has a width, and if it's wrapped in a div use this style:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img src="arrow.gif"></div>
```

However, you could get a direct answer if we seen the code.